# httrack getting tumblr photoposts but not photosets; why?

Tags: download, wget, httrack

I'm trying to save tumblr image posts.

For a post with one image, like this
http://textsfromthepurikyua.tumblr.com/post/124075150094/textsfromthepurikyua-image-cure-heart
httrack -n gets that image. (I'd usually put a bunch of exclusions on to remove a lot of extraneous files, but that's not important.)

For a post with multiple images, like this
http://textsfromthepurikyua.tumblr.com/post/124494287912/textsfromthepurikyua-photoset-first-image-is
httrack -n won't get any of the 5 main images, but it will get the other images on the page (which I don't generally care about).

What should I do instead? If it matters, I want the same command to work on single-image and multiple-image posts.

I've never used wget before today, but if there's an easier fix for this problem there, I'll accept it. It seems that wget -p should be equivalent to httrack -n, but it doesn't get the main image on even the single-image post.

Comment: Doesn't Tumble load posts/photos as you scroll? I can't look at Tumble post at the moment, but are you basically just wanting to download all images from a single webpage regardless of content?

Comment: I'm not talking about downloading a whole tumblog (I did that in the past), but individual posts. I have some lists of hundreds of tumblr posts I'd like to automatically download. That blog I used in the example happens to not have that annoying thing where "You might like" posts load at the bottom. And ideally, I'd prefer to exclude those somehow from blogs that have them, but that's another issue.